# JAR version control

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Can i generate jar from eclipse with version number for the jar created newly for every jar export?

Regards,

magggi.

Comment: Probably not. You should use something like Ant to include a timestamp (or revision number) for the build in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run a build script from Eclipse. If you use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), check out these tasks:

- [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html)  to increment a build number held in a file.
- [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with a [filterset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) to replace version tokens in MANIFEST.MF
- [jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) to jar the filtered manifest, classes, resources etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you will probably want to use ant and do some token replacements in the jar filename.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Eclipse builder for the project that kicks off an ANT script.